# How to restore a particular git branch

Tags: git

Here the scenario, first of all in the master tree there are two folders

```
├── foo1
│   └── index.php
└── foo2
    └── index.php
```

Then I create a branch ***b1*** and add into two more folders.

```
├── foo1
│   └── index.php
├── foo2
│   └── index.php
├── foo3
│   └── index.php
└── foo4
    └── index.php
```

After that I command `git add .` and force switch back to master `git co -f master` without `commit` command. The current tree now has been gone the foo3 and foo4 folder but still remains the branch ***b1***

```
├── foo1
│   └── index.php
└── foo2
    └── index.php
```

My question is how to restore folder 3 and 4 from the branch ***b1*** ? I tried `git co b1` but the folder 3,4 still disappear.

Comment: You never committed anything on branch `b1`, so it still points to the same commit as `master` does. That’s why checking it out won’t restore those files.

Comment: try `git stash` on branch `b1` before moving back to `master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'git fsck' to find dangling blobs. Here is an example:

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 54578ea3b3fb8d790bc5e19e36b52e601ec5433a
dangling blob f719efd430d52bcfc8566a43b2eb655688d38871
```

You can list them directly with:

```
$ ls .git/lost-found/other/
54578ea3b3fb8d790bc5e19e36b52e601ec5433a
f719efd430d52bcfc8566a43b2eb655688d38871
```

and then recover them one-by-one.

```
$ cat .git/lost-found/other/54578ea3b3fb8d790bc5e19e36b52e601ec5433a 
<contents of file>
$ mv .git/lost-found/other/54578ea3b3fb8d790bc5e19e36b52e601ec5433a <my-file-one>
```

I think you'll need to reconstruct the directory structure.

Comment: `git fsck --lost-found` doesn't show any blob. Since when I `git co -f master` with the flag force it complete removes files in branch as jthill says

Comment: Is there nothing in .git/lost-found/other ?

Comment: Note: before I composed my response, I reproduced your commands and saw the two blobs (listed in my response) with two files that I blew away with 'git checkout -f' as you did.  So, check .git/lost-found.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them back as GoZoner says, but when you did `checkout -f` you told git to blow away anything getting in the way of that checkout -- that's everything in the index, and anything in the worktree that changed between the indexed state and the new branch.

In particular, with the `git add` you marked `foo{3,4}/index.php` as tracked files; during checkout, if a file is tracked in the current index and untracked in the new index, then it was present in the tracked state and now isn't, so switching to match the new tracked state necessarily means deleting the file from the worktree.

Ordinarily, git will refuse to delete uncommitted content for tracked files, with a more-or-less explanatory message, but you specified `--force`.  Don't do that.